# Stop footer overlapping the content

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the footer that overlaps the content.
See fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjsu58/

I tried lots of hints but nothing seems to work, I think the CSS for the footer is OK, maybe somewhere in the content's one is the problem.

```css
#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;*/
    left: 0;
}
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">
        
<h2>Tarif</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
<div id="footer">
    <center>
        <script src="/Scripts/script.js"></script><a href=""><img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;"><img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;"><img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;"><img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_1.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="1" style="border:0px;"><img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_2.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="2" style="border:0px;"></a>
        <span class="fl-footer-site-stat-key">Numar Vizualizari</span>
    </center>
    <footer>
        <span>© 2015 - Diagnoza Auto</span>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean overlapping? The footer is transparent, that's why you can see text through it. Give it a `background: "white";` for example

Comment: I want the footer to stay to the bottom of the page. If the page changes the height( for example on a mobile device) I want a scroll bar to appear and the footer stay fixed.

Comment: Oh, it's the position `fixed`. Others have already given you the correct answer

Comment: Still not what I want, see it in full screen. the footer will go over the content and hide it..

Comment: @AndreiMaieras see https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjsu58/6/embedded/result/ its not overlapping any content. You can see in any view.

Comment: Not sure what you intend then. What do you expect to happen when the window is resized and the text won't fit the area above the footer?

Comment: @chiapa on laptops scroll bar to appear and on mobile device the footer goes down making room for content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated position `fixed` of element. Use following css:

```
#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;/*updated*/
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjsu58/6/) : changed background for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`

```
#footer {
border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
padding: 3px;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
position:relative; /* Changed this */
bottom: 0;
/* overflow: hidden;
z-index: -1;*/
left: 0;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjsu58/2/)

Comment: doing this will indeed make the footer not overlap the content, but it brings the footer up, just below the content.. i want it to stay at the bottom of the page

Comment: Then change it to position:fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: fixed;` and set the `z-index` so it's above the text. And apply a background color. Like so:

```
#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Changing down the height until reaching last row of text will make the footer overlapp the content and the scrollbar does not appear making the last 2 lines of text inaccesible see here http://diagnoza-auto.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: The scrollbar appears. The window just has to be small enough. If you want it to appear earlier, change the height of `.body-content` or set a `min-height` of 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xrdjsu58/10/) then?

Insert a media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { 
   #footer { display: none; } 
}
```

```js
#
footer {
  border - top: 1px solid# d3d3d3;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100 % ;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;*/
  left: 0;
}
.body - content {
  padding - left: 15px;
  padding - right: 15px;
  padding - bottom: 75px;
}@
media all and(max - width: 480px) {#
  footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container body-content">

  <h2>Tarif</h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
  Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit
  vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
  Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
<div id="footer">
  <center>
    <script src="/Scripts/script.js"></script>
    <a href="">
      <img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;">
      <img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;">
      <img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_0.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="0" style="border:0px;">
      <img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_1.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="1" style="border:0px;">
      <img src="http://services.webestools.com/images/s3_2.gif" class="cpt_viu_28885" alt="2" style="border:0px;">
    </a>
    <span class="fl-footer-site-stat-key">Numar Vizualizari</span>

  </center>
  <footer> <span>© 2015 - Diagnoza Auto</span>

  </footer>
</div>
```

Resize the width and at some point the footer will disappear.

Comment: In your snippet the footer is just bellow the last line of text, I want it on the bottom of the page, and if I add content scroll bar appear and footer goes down. When I shrink the page the footer should go up until it reaches the first line of text and then it stops and the scroll bar appear. But I think I'm too picky.

Comment: http://diagnoza-auto.azurewebsites.net/ look at this I added your code aboeve. Shrink height of the page until the footer reaches the text, it covers the first line of text widhout createing the scroll bar.